JS and C# classes over net
I have been learning networking coding using C# (WebSockets) and used MessagePack to pack and send classes over the net.
What I would like to do however is use Javascript as client and C# for the server. Is this doable?
So far i have used javascript MessagePack implemenatations to encode json and then decode that on the server
But can I also send C#/JS classes over net? MessagePack C# has Deserialize function but I dont know if I can deserialize JS classes via that (in the server)?
thx!

The question is missing the point. You don't send classes. You send bytes. Ideally those bytes form messages formatted via a protocol with which you can encode data that is understood independently of a specific language. Msgpack is such a protocol/format. So you should be able to send messages between JS and C# if you have respective codec libs on each end of the line.

Yes i know its bytes you send not classes. but my point is how to turn class to bytes and back. I discovered kawanet (https://www.npmjs.com/package/msgpack-lite) implementation which can do that codec thing you are talking about. So it seems it maybe indeed possible to use codec but I'm still unsure if I can have codec working on C# as well. But i have to do more research on that. It sure seems like quite a bit effort to make it working, I was hoping single encode/decode functions

If your javascript classes are properly serialized to JSON in the client, they should be able to be deserialized in the server by any good deserializer, not necessarily just in C#. JSON is a data format, it is not bound to a specific programming language.

Yes but i was thinking the JSON approach might be slower when compared pure class sending over the net. Which i did for C# server-client. and now my question is can I do same with JS client

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but if your question is only about performance of json versus messagepack the following link might help: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/json-vs-messagepack-battle-data-efficiency-akshay-singh-kanawat-7dx2c

thanks for the link, good read! Basically my question still is can I have MessagePack C# server and MessagePack JS client (without using JSON)

I think that the answer to the question "Can I ..." should be: "It depends."  Performance is a matter of many things. Generally I would think that JS is slower than C#, but if the hardware is performant enough, you might not even notice the difference. Also, how complex are the objects you want to transfer? Even if the performance difference would be a factor 10, the difference between 5 ms and 50ms will not be noticed, but the difference between 500ms en 5 sec will.

The main concern is the bandwidth. Other than that Javascript should be fine for my needs, I have used it before to make a game and draw graphics etc.

Unless you exchange large objects at a very high rate, i don't think bandwidth should be a thing to worry about.

Still i would like to go for speed. in the link you posted the review said MessagePack is much faster than JSON

Well in that case your question is answered, isn't it? If you agree, please mark the answer as accepted.

it's not answered. please see my comment (comment #3)

I'm afraid I don't get it anymore. The amount of bytes produced by messagepack is less than produced by json. Why is that not an answer if bandwidth is your main concern?

I see there's misunderstanding of what I meant by can I use MessagePack. I meant is it technically possible, does JS MessagePack implementations have the required functionality to move data between C# server and JS client. I have checked two MessagePack implementations for JS but did not find the required functions other than for JSON encode/decode

Are you telling me that you found two messagepack implementations that encode/decode json but not messagepack? I'm sorry but I think I'm lost on this one. Probably need a strong cup of coffee.

yes there is few implementations here https://msgpack.org/ if you scroll down. Only got JSON working but maybe I just need to keep searching but wasnt sure if C# - JS is doable
